# Best way to power small design isolated from outlets?

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, battery-operated

I have a project involving a low-power MCU, an IR-distance sensor, and some LED strips. I want the entire project to be fairly out of sight and housed in a cabinet (it's just LED strips that turn on when the cabinet door opens), so I'm looking for an inconspicuous and durable way to power said project without outlet access.

When the cabinet is open I will be drawing between 1-1.1A @ 24V from the power supply. When closed, I will be drawing around 20mA @ 24V.

Right now the best I got is finding the smallest Lipo or NiMH battery package that wouldn't need to be charged with annoying frequency.

I don't have any hard requirements for length of power - something needing a recharge once a week would be fine I suppose, but preferably longer.  My budget would somewhere in the sub $50 range. Any suggestions?

Comment: how low-power is low-power? yes you can use a battery pack. But have you considered finding a way to power it from an outlet anyway? Recharging cabinet lights seems annoying. Really annoying. You *will* stop bothering to charge them eventually.

Comment: Best way always requires specs what's best in your case, including a budget, because the best way could be impossible due to limitations we don't know, and much expensive than just hiring an electrician to wire a maind outlet for you.

Comment: Edited in those constraints.

Comment: This is a shopping question, please edit make it a design question to keep it on topic. I'll answer the design portion of the question.

Comment: I question the use of an IR sensor to detect the door opening, and I assume that this is what is drawing the 200mA when the door is closed. A reed switch or Hall effect device and magnet would draw very little when the door is closed. And I don't know why your IR sensor needs so much power. You need to show your components and the complete circuit to get a meaningful answer instead of a guess.

Comment: @InBedded16 Is it 200mA or 0.2mA when the door is closed?

Comment: 24W when it is open? You really got 2500 lumens in a cabinet?

Comment: @voltagespike sorry actually neither of those are correct, its a 20mA draw when closed.

Comment: @PStechPaul I appreciate the advice but I'm not asking for any changes or input on my design, only the power supply aspect. You really shouldn't need components or the circuit to be able to give meaningful input - the power draw values are listed with a description of the circuit behavior, that should be enough.

Comment: @InBedded16 There is still not enough info to suggest you a battery. You have not told how long you want to run the lights. Is it 24h per day, or 1h per day, or what? You need that to calculate battery capacity you need to have power for a week.

Answer (score 1):

At 1A of power, for max power for a full week with the cabinet open you would need 168Amp-Hours from a 24V battery. For min power, at 0.2mA with the cabinet shut you would need ~0.34Amp-Hours, which isn't much.

Considering if the door was open for ~1Hr/week, you would need a 2Amp-Hour battery to cover your needs.

Comment: I believe the quiescent current draw was stated at 0.2mA, which would make the weekly current draw 34mAh.  I have no idea what the cabinet is being used for but if it's opened for 30 seconds, 10 times a day, 7 days a week, you're only at a grand total of 675mAh or 16Wh.  You would still need an inconveniently large battery pack but not car battery-sized.

Comment: @vir Yeah, I though it would be in the amps range... totally overlooked that. Thanks for the catch

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thank you for the answer, although the power draw calculations themselves are not an issue. Just trying to find a way to deliver that power that fits my project requirements.

Comment: Yeah, if your looking for a suggestion for a specific battery, that would be off topic. If your looking for a charging circuit, that would be on topic. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: I see that the OP has again changed the quiescent current draw, now 20 mA. The specification for a suitable battery is simple enough if the total time drawing 1A with the lights ON and the total time at 20 mA with lights OFF is known. For one week, or 168 hours, the minimum requirement would be 3.36 A-h. A battery should not be discharged below about 80%, so a 4 A-h battery would be about right. @InBedded16 would need to determine how often and how long the lights will be on, and adjust accordingly.